# string and special character in ++ NDK

Tags: c++, utf-8

I need to pass (in c++ NDK) a string value with "Ç", and make a loop with the string. 
But this string length is bigger than normal and i cant get "Ç" character. 
Any Help-me, please?
i do not use text file. This value made a variable and id nedd get all characters values, with or without special characters.

Comment: In what character encoding?

Comment: i´m use eclipse and i configurate workspace option and content types to UTF-8 but i compile c++ library with ndk-build and i dont know how define enconding in this...

Comment: So, the character code is 0xC7, which translates into UTF as c3 87, so `"\xC3\x87"` should do the trick.

Comment: but for example: "AVANÇAR". This word contain 7 characters. But string.legth() return 8 characters, disturbing my loop.

Comment: The character "Ç" turn on 2 characters, understand?

Comment: Yes, exactly, You need to take that into account when you process the string. It's part of "dealing with UTF-8". The SIMPLEST solution is to just convert it to 16- or 32-bit characters first (e.g use `wstring`), and then you don't have to worry about multi-part characters. Otherwise, you'll have do "understand" UTF-8 characters as being part of the text.

Comment: i do not understand. I have not had this problem with the PC version compiled in mingw. only with ndk. how come?

Comment: I have no idea, and since you are not actually sharing any code, it's quite hard to know exactly what may be wrong with the code or your assumptions of how things work. [Maybe on the PC your encoding is indeed 8-bit extended ASCII, rather than UTF-8 - or you are using 16-bit characters, which would solve the problem until you get to the more obscure characters in Asian langugages, etc)

Comment: `string.length` returns size in bytes (`char`s), not actual characters. The nomenclature for `char` comes from the olden days when a character was exactly one byte but since the adoption of Unicode, that is no longer so.

Answer (score 0):

In UTF-8, a character is one to six bytes (`char`s) long. [See Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description) for more details. To obtain the length, the easiest way is to skip all continuation bytes:

```
size_t length = 0;
for (char c : text)
    if ((c & 0xC0) != 0x80) // The first two bits are not 10
        ++length;
```

The length is increased at the first byte of each new character so you should be able to change the cycle to get character sequences for you.